# Reading and searching files using systemcalls in C

Tags: c, system-calls

I tried reading from the file "hello.txt" but it doesn't enter the while loop at all. The read function returns 0 on EOF and -1 on error. I'm trying to search for the word in w if it exists in the file or not. I'm reading characters from the file and comparing them to w[].

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int fd;
  char c;
  int i=0;
  int bytesread;
  int flag=1;

  char w[]={'h','e','l','l','o'};

  if((fd=open("hello.txt",O_RDONLY,0))!=-1){ //if 1

    bytesread = read(fd,&c,0);

    if(bytesread!=-1){      //if 2

    while(bytesread!=0)
    {                      //while

      if(c==w[i])
      {                   //if 3
        i++;
        flag=0;
      }                  //end of f3

      else if(flag==0&&i!=0)   
      {                  // else 3
        i=0; 
        flag=1;

      }                  // end of else 3

      bytesread = read(fd,&c,0);
    }   //end of while

    }else  //end of if 2
      printf("couldn't read file.\n");

    }else //end of if 1
    printf("Couldn't open file for read.\n");

  } //end of main
```

Comment: You ask the system to read zero bytes. Instead, ask it to read one byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

[read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) reads `count` bytes from the file. You're asking it to read zero bytes when doing `bytesread = read(fd,&c,0);`. Change it to `bytesread = read(fd,&c,1);`

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{

    int fd;
    char c;
    int bytesread;

    if ((fd = open("hello.txt", O_RDONLY, 0)) != -1) {

        while ((bytesread = read(fd, &c, 1)) == 1) 
            printf("read %d bytes [%c]\n", bytesread, c);

    } else          
        printf("Couldn't open file for read.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`read(fd,&c,0)` asks the system to read **zero bytes**, and it shouldn't be what you want to do.

You should ask the system to read one byte by `read(fd,&c,1)`.